# Wordpress - is_page_template

Tags: php, wordpress, responsiveness

I have been using the following code to set the column width on certain pages within a wordpress site:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'fullwidthhome.php' ) ) {
    global $content_width;
    $content_width = 1080; /* pixels */
  }
  elseif ( is_page_template( 'wideContent.php' ) ) {
    global $content_width;
    $content_width = 1080; /* pixels */
  }
```

This works great on pages with custom templates, but I not quite sure how to get it to work for custom post types.

It doesn't seem to work when I set the the template to that of my custom post type:

```
  elseif ( is_page_template( 'single-widecontent.php' ) ) {
    global $content_width;
    $content_width = 1080; /* pixels */
  }
```

Any thoughts?

TIA!

Steph

Answer (score 0):

How about this function `get_post_type()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. It should be as follows.

```
else if ( 'widecontent' == get_post_type() ) {

global $content_width;
$content_width = 1080; /* pixels */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually went for `is_singular ('wideContent')` in the end :)

Thanks guys!!